# Null pointer exception when inserting data into Android SQLite Database

Tags: database, pointers, exception, null, android-sqlite

I'm just starting an Android Studio project and Ive created a small player database and I have been trying to add player details into the database. However each time the program crashes with a null pointer exception. A quick debgug suggests the problem is with the call to the OnClickListener in the OnCreate method. What changes need to be made to the code? Thanks

```
public class DatabaseHelper {

    // Declare instance of DBHelper class, context and SQLiteDatabase
    private DBHelper ourDbHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDb;

    // Initialise the database and table names and version
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Club";
    private static final String PLAYER_TABLE_NAME = "Players";

    //Initialise the PLAYER_TABLE_NAME field names
    private static final String PLAYER_ID = "player_id";
    private static final String PLAYER_SURNAME = "player_surname";
    private static final String PLAYER_FORENAME = "player_forename";
    private static final String PLAYER_AGE = "player_age";
    private static final String PLAYER_DOB = "player_dob";

     private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


        // This constructor takes the context, db name and db version as 
    parameters
        // and applies them to the DBHelper class
        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        // This constructor takes context as parameter and assigns it to 
    variable

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            //Executes the following queries to create the Player Table
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + PLAYER_TABLE_NAME + " (" + PLAYER_ID 
    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + PLAYER_FORENAME + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + PLAYER_SURNAME + 
    "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    PLAYER_AGE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + PLAYER_DOB + "DATE 
    NOT NULL );");
        }//OnCreate

    @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int 
    newVersion) {

            // if table is upgraded or already exists
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PLAYER_TABLE_NAME);

            onCreate(db);
        }//OnUpgrade
    }//DBHelperClass

    // Constructor takes a context as a parameter and assigns it to 
    ourContext
    public DatabaseHelper (Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }//constructor

    // Open writable database and allow to be modified
    public DatabaseHelper open() throws SQLException {
        ourDbHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
        myDb = ourDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }//open

    //method to close the db to modification
    public void close() {
        ourDbHelper.close();
    }//close

    // method to create an entry to the Player table with player attributes as parameters
    public long createEntry (String forename, String surname, String age, String dob){

        //contentValues will hold the information to be added to the database
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        //Using put method, insert the parameters into the fields in the table
        contentValues.put(PLAYER_FORENAME, forename);
        contentValues.put(PLAYER_SURNAME, surname);
        contentValues.put(PLAYER_AGE,age);
        contentValues.put(PLAYER_DOB, String.valueOf(dob));

        //insert the values into the player table
        //assign to variable result to check if data added correctly
        return myDb.insert(PLAYER_TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

    }//createEntry
```

Here is the AddPlayer activity class

```
public class AddPlayer extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //declare variables
    Button confirmAdd;
    EditText editSurname, editForename, editAge, editDOB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_player_activity);

        //Initialise variables
        editForename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPlayerForename);
        editSurname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPlayerSurname);
        editAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPlayerAge);
        editDOB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPlayerDOB);

        confirmAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addPlayerBtn);

        //set onclicklisteners
        confirmAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        String forename = editForename.getText().toString();
        String surname = editSurname.getText().toString();
        String age = editAge.getText().toString();
        String dob = editDOB.getText().toString();

        DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(AddPlayer.this);
        myDb.open();

        myDb.createEntry(forename, surname, age, dob);


        Toast.makeText(AddPlayer.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Comment: Try changing `DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(AddPlayer.this);` to `DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(v.getContext());`

Answer (score 0):

### Change this

```
DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(AddPlayer.this);

myDb.open()
```

### To

```
DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this.getContext());

myDb.open();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you explain why is `AddPlayer.this` incorrect and a possible cause of NPE?